# Multiple clickable items in ListView inside android widget

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-widget

I'm trying to make ListView in a widget where there are multiple clickable items in each row. For example, if each row has data containing a link, one button in the row to open the link and another to share the link.

**Sample code:**

Widget layout

```
<LinearLayout...>

<TextView../>
<ListView with id="list_view" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Each list row in the ListView has:

```
<LinearLayout with id="listRowParent">

<TextView../>
<Button with id="openBtn"/>
<Button with id="shareBtn"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I'm able to set onClick of each row using

```
remoteViews.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.list_view,
                    *<PendingIntent>*); //in onUpdate
```

and `remoteView.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.openBtn, *fillIntent*); // in adapter`

which works fine, but I can't have setPendingIntentTemplate for a list row button by doing remoteViews.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.shareBtn,
                        );
since nothing happens on clicking the button if I do this.

**Question:**
Is what I'm attempting possible? If yes, help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: I suspect your problem with the button is that it is overlapped by the TextView. In that case, you need to modify your layout by using idea of layout_weight, gravity, or setting the widths (which is not flexible). This way the button is not overlapped and visible. Add large text for your buttons so that you can see them clearly in the Listview. Normally I would give samples. But for now, you can try it out first and see what we can do.

Comment: I'm using layout_weight, and it's unlikely that the button is overlapped, since  the button gets highlighted when it is touched. I have tried removing the text view and keeping just two buttons but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My bad. I should be using

```
remoteViews.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.list_view,
                    *<PendingIntent>*);
```

for both the buttons, but I was trying to use the button's ID directly in the second. Got fixed.

Comment: I am facing the exact issue. Can you please share getViewAt() code?